# Object reference not set to an instance of an object on DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is driving me crazy! I am trying to create a drop down list that gets it's values from the database. I am new to MVC, so it's probably something simple, but I can't figure it out. Please help!

View Model:

```
public class LoadInputModel
{
    public GeoRegion GeoRegion { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GeoRegion> Description { get; set; }
```

}

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LoadShape(LoadInputModel LoadInputModel)
    {
        LoadInputModel.Description = db.GeoRegions.Select(a => a);

        return View(LoadInputModel);
}
```

Here is my htmlhelper:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Description,Model.Description.Select(c => new SelectListItem { Text = c.Description, Value = c.Id.ToString() }), "-----Select Category----")
```

Comment: Which line produces the error?

Comment: I get the error on the htmlhelper

Answer (score 0):

I guess your `Description`  property value is `null`, So you may need to initialize it before assigning some values to that

```
 if( LoadInputModel.Description==null)
 {
     LoadInputModel.Description=new List<GeoRegion>();
 }
 LoadInputModel.Description = db.GeoRegions.Select(a => a);
```

Or you can do it in the class level itself so taht you dont need to do in many places

```
public class LoadInputModel
{
    public GeoRegion GeoRegion { get; set; }
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<GeoRegion> Description { get; set; }

    public LoadInputModel()
    {
       if(Description==null)
        {
         Description=new List<GeoRegion>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I found the problem. It had to do with my model.